# Get html output from a jcr node in CQ5

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I wanted to know if there is a way to get the rendered HTML output of a Page node in CQ5 without hitting the actual url. I have the Page node and I want to get the rendered HTML output of that Page node programmatically in java and store it in a string without hitting the page URL.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node itself it's just a data. Sling framework responsible for rendering this data. It use a bunch of rules to determine how this data should be rendered.[Sling Script Resolution Cheet Sheet](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/sling_cheatsheet/_jcr_content/par/image.img.png) As Sling is web framework it renders data via http requests.

To emulate this request in CQ/AEM I suggest to use [com.day.cq.contentsync.handler.util.RequestResponseFactory](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/contentsync/handler/util/RequestResponseFactory.html) service

```
import org.apache.sling.engine.SlingRequestProcessor;
import com.day.cq.contentsync.handler.util.RequestResponseFactory;

@Reference
private RequestResponseFactory requestResponseFactory;

@Reference
private SlingRequestProcessor requestProcessor;

public String doStuff(){
    HttpServletRequest request = requestResponseFactory.createRequest("GET", "/path/to/your/node.html");
    request.setAttribute(WCMMode.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, WCMMode.DISABLED);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    HttpServletResponse response = requestResponseFactory.createResponse(out);

    requestProcessor.processRequest(request, response, resourceResolver);        
    return out.toString(response.getCharacterEncoding());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can access node by providing a correct view. As you need rendered html view, use .html with your node to get rendered html. So your node path will be

```
/content/path/to/page/jcr:content/par/node_name.html
```

Now to read html programmatically, you can make an http request to above path from your path, and save response as string.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: Please explain what you have done, because concept wise this approach should work for your usecase.

Comment: I have a page node which has several chhild nodes of different resourceType and I wanted the html output of the page node exactly the same way as rendered by the browser, your approach works only for a single node and not for all the child nodes.

Comment: In this case, you should have a par node below your page node. Your data selector should include path of par. ie "/content/path/to/page/jcr:content/par.html" and it will return html of all component dropped in par